# If you lost the game disk could you buy the first copy of the game and play the game with the DLCs

Tags: xbox-one, destiny

The title says it all. If I get the beginning disk, will i be able to play my DLC as well with the game.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work.  All games have to be installed onto the Xbox, and the CD is used just to start them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

**The disc is only needed to verify ownership of the game if you have not bought it digitally.** Everything else is tied to either your PSN/XboxLive account (ie, the account that have purchased the DLC) or your Bungie.net account. (which is the same as your PSN/XBL account, but generally your characters/stats are stored here.)